# 2008 Altima, power windows and locks don't work, Intelligent key system doesn't work. No power at master switch?

Tags: nissan, power-windows, altima, bcm, power-door-lock

I've checked all the fuses and relays and they are good. Had a lock smith cut me another key, however, said that he was unable to code the FOB because of the failures within my intelligent key system.
With the failures of my power windows and locks, what could be my culprit? BCM?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My first blush would be the BCM, considering this is what controls the area of your vehicle you're having issues with on most cars.